# What's the simplest way to send emails using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, email, gmail-api, nodemailer

About two years ago, I created a Node.js application that would send emails periodically through Gmail's Less Secure Apps option. This worked quite well, but they recently got rid of it. I have G-Suite email addresses under my domain that I would like to send emails from, but the new Gmail API takes quite a bit of effort to set up and maintain. Is there a way that I can use Node.js to send emails from those addresses, but in a simpler way? Could I possibly use another SMTP server, like Yahoo or iCloud, with Nodemailer?

Comment: You can use a service like Mailgun, Sendgrid or Amazon SES. It's possible to it up in a way that it can also send with a `From` address showing your Gmail address.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to continue as you are just create an apps password.

otherwise you can configure a service account and set up domain wide deligation through your workspace domain account.

The service account will be able to send email on behalf of a user on your domain without any authorization needed.   This is probably the most robust solution